# Cannot convert value of type '[String : String?]' to expected argument type '[String : AnyObject?]'

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, mapkit

I'm new on Swift and I followed this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/90971/introduction-mapkit-swift-tutorial about MapKit. The problem is that I got an error on this line of code

```
let placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: self.coordinate, addressDictionary: addressDict)
```

The error is described on title. The method which contains this line is:

```
func mapItem() -> MKMapItem {
    let addressDict = [String(kABPersonAddressStreetKey): self.subtitle]
    let placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: self.coordinate, addressDictionary: addressDict)

    let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)
    mapItem.name = self.title

    return mapItem
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to cast your `subtitle` as `AnyObject` as shown below:

```
let addressDict = [String(kABPersonAddressStreetKey): self.subtitle as! AnyObject]
```

and your complete code will be:

```
func mapItem() -> MKMapItem {
    let addressDict = [String(kABPersonAddressStreetKey): self.subtitle as! AnyObject]
    let placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: self.coordinate, addressDictionary: addressDict)

    let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)
    mapItem.name = self.title

    return mapItem
  }
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I uprooted because I don't get swift. :) i don't know why it complained when I tried to cast the dictionary... this is it

Comment: That helped . Thank u so much